# Is it possible to have a Weblink open up a chat in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to have a link on a webpage open up a chat in teams with a chatbot. Is this possible to do? I doubt it would be possible to open up the local app, but maybe for the web app portion of teams? I tried just copy pasting the url when I was in the chat with the bot, but that didn't work for other people.

Comment: You could get the link to open a chat with the bot by clicking on the Microsoft Teams channel in the Bot Framework or Azure portal where you have created the bot. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YNC7.png). Please let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the link to open a chat with the bot by clicking on the Microsoft Teams channel in the Bot Framework or Azure portal where you have created the bot. Here is an example:
[image: image description]